# Windows 8 adding images

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

I'm trying to add images to my hello world app (HTML / JavaScript).

I am able to add the standard images (logo.png, smalllogo.png etc), but adding:
`<img src="images/testImg.png">` won't show, when testing the app.

The image is located in the images folder, but won't show. What's wrong here?

Comment: did you preload the images?

Comment: Have you added them to your AppManifest xml?

Comment: I haven't preloaded them - as i'm not sure how to do that ?
I'm looking at the app manifest, but i'm unable to find anywhere to declare them ?
Its all new to me, so i apologize for the low level

Comment: I am simply just adding <img src='images/test.png'> in the html, and the output is: RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the image needs to be added by clicking "add->existing item->image". Then it gets loaded and will be available in the app.